# Deserializing returning null even though the response is 200

Tags: c#, wpf, deserialization

I've checked the response, this gives me back the information I need (which is not null) and gives me a response of 200. Whenever I try to deserialize the JSON returned, it shows null even though there should be information given.

This only happens when I try to grab one project, when I grab multiple this all works. I've tried to remove the `ProjectList` class and tried to grab the information directly from the `Project` class but this also returns nothing.

```
var client = new RestClient("website goes here");

var request = new RestRequest($"/api/v2/projects/{Global.PSlug}");
request.Method = Method.GET;
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", Global.ApiToken));

var response = client.Execute(request);

var deserialize = new JsonDeserializer();

ProjectList output = deserialize.Deserialize<ProjectList>(response);

HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;
int numericStatusCode = (int)statusCode;

if (numericStatusCode == 200)
{
    MessageBox.Show(response.Content.ToString()); // gives info
    output.Projects[0].Title = Global.PTitle;
    output.Projects[0].Title = Global.PDescription;

    ProjectTitle.Text = Global.PTitle;
    ProjectDesc.Text = Global.PDescription;
}
```

Classes for deserializing

```
class ProjectList
{
    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Deadline { get; set; }
    public string User_Id { get; set; }
    public string Created_At { get; set; }
    public string Updated_At { get; set; }
}
```

Response is:

```
{
    "Message": "OK",
    "Project": {
        "id": 13,
        "title": "Api",
        "slug": "apitest",
        "description": "Api",
        "deadline": "2020-03-01 00:00:00",
        "user_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2020-02-28 14:53:27",
        "updated_at": "2020-02-28 14:53:27"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the JSON you are getting and the Class you are using for deserialization are different. The JSON would require something like below.

```
class ApiResponse
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}

class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Deadline { get; set; }
    public string User_Id { get; set; }
    public string Created_At { get; set; }
    public string Updated_At { get; set; }
}
```